# how to pass value from controller to gsp page

Tags: grails, grails-controller

i want to pass the value of i to create .gsp page ,how to do that

```
def save = {
    def billingPeriodInstance = new BillingPeriod(params)
    DatabaseImpController obj= new DatabaseImpController()

   int i = obj.setbillPeriod()

   if(i== 1){
        render(view: "create")
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

just use

```
render(view: "create", model:[i: i])
```